# Generate html <table> content with JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, html

```
var array = [
['name1', 'material1', 'number1', 'place1', 'country1'],
['name2', 'material2', 'number2', 'place2', 'country2']
];
```

This is the js array

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Material</th>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>Place</th>
        <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is the html table i have

Now i want the values of the array generated in my table with pure JS. How is this possible?

Comment: Have you searched or tried anything so far? do you have any JS knowledge? Do some effort and show us where you struggle and we will help for sure.

Comment: Yes i have worked with JS before, only i have no idea how to work this out. @ZakariaAcharki

Comment: refer this https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp

Comment: Please do add your progress so far in your post to address a specific issue and not just ask for a given desired result from a given value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate HTML table from 2D JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164655/generate-html-table-from-2d-javascript-array) and [Javascript create table with for loop and array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41947600)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement

Comment: Her you go @JackKiurre take a look to this post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38393375/4281779

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over to the array and create a HTML string with `<tr>` and `<td>` then apply those to the inner HTML of the `table` element:

```js
var array = [
['name1', 'material1', 'number1', 'place1', 'country1'],
['name2', 'material2', 'number2', 'place2', 'country2']
];
var nHTML = document.querySelector('table').innerHTML;
array.forEach(function(arrItem){
  var td = '<tr>';
  arrItem.forEach(function(item){
    td += '<td>'+item+'</td>' ;
  });
  nHTML += td + '</tr>';
});
document.querySelector('table').innerHTML = nHTML;
```

```html
<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Material</th>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>Place</th>
        <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Works perfect, THANKS!

Comment: @JackKiurre you can tick mark the answer if it was helpful to you

Answer (score 1):

Check this fiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/a3r8ze0g/

You need to itinerate the array like this:

> arr.forEach(function(elem){ //Where arr is the array

```
var arr = [
['name1', 'material1', 'number1', 'place1', 'country1'],
['name2', 'material2', 'number2', 'place2', 'country2']
];

var tabla = document.getElementById('newTable');

arr.forEach(function(elem){

    var tr = tabla.insertRow();
  tr.innerHTML = '<td>'+elem[0]+'</td><td>'+elem[1]+'</td><td>'+elem[2]+'</td><td>'+elem[3]+'</td><td>'+elem[4]+'</td>';
})
```

```js
var arr = [
['name1', 'material1', 'number1', 'place1', 'country1'],
['name2', 'material2', 'number2', 'place2', 'country2']
];

var tabla = document.getElementById('newTable');

arr.forEach(function(elem){
  
 var tr = tabla.insertRow();
  tr.innerHTML = '<td>'+elem[0]+'</td><td>'+elem[1]+'</td><td>'+elem[2]+'</td><td>'+elem[3]+'</td><td>'+elem[4]+'</td>';
})
```

```html
<table id="newTable">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Material</th>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>Place</th>
        <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```